# How to show that $\sin(iy)=i\sinh y$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I know that $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Then substituting $x=iy$:
$$\sin(iy)=\frac{e^{i(iy)}-e^{-i(iy)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-y}-e^{y}}{2i}$$
Then, according to my lecture handout (this step is the one I don't get) it follows that:
$$\sin(iy)=i\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}=i\sinh y$$
Whats going on there?

Comment: use $1/i=-i$ and the definition of $\sinh y = {e^y-e^{-y}\over 2}$

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to multiply by $\frac{i}{i}$:
$$\sin(iy)=\frac{e^{i(iy)}-e^{-i(iy)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-y}-e^{y}}{2i}=\frac{i}{i}\frac{e^{-y}-e^{y}}{2i}=i\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}=i\sinh ( y).$$

Answer (score 1):

You use that $-1/i = i$, to get the result.